# »Beispiel zu« vs. »Beispiel für«

Tags: grammar, word-usage, difference

> Ein paar Beispiele **für das** Wort *gehen* / **zu dem** Wort *gehen*:
>
> 1. Ich gehe jeden Tag ins Fitnessstudio, um fit zu bleiben.
> 2. Ich gehe in den Park, um zu trainieren.

Meine Frage ist, was ist der Unterschied zwischen „Beispiel für“ und „Beispiel zu“? Haben sie dieselbe Bedeutung im Sinne von „example for“?

Comment: "Ein Beispiel für" lässt sich glaube ich manchmal mit "an example of" ganz gut übersetzen. "Ein Beispiel für ein gutes Buch." - "An example of a good book." In dem Fall ginge "Beispiel zu" nicht.

Comment: "Gestern, im Stadion, sahen wir ein klassisches Beispiel für passives Abseits." Dagegen "... Beispiel zu ..." würde nicht passen, vielleicht weil es zwar exemplarisch ist, aber nicht als Exempel gegeben wurde, sondern ein Exemplar in freier Wildbahn war.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Beispiel für" wird verwendet, wenn das Beispiel ein Exemplar oder eine Instanz des beschriebenen Konzepts ist. Ein Beispiel für eine Frucht ist ein Apfel. Ein Beispiel für ein MMORPG ist World of Warcraft.

"Beispiel zu" wird verwendet, wenn das Beispiel den Kontext des beschriebenen Konzepts illustriert oder es ermöglicht, das Konzept anzuwenden. Die Beispiele die ich hier schreibe sind Beispiele zu den Phrasen. Ein Beispiel zur Addition ist "1 + 1 = ?". Dementsprechend wird diese Phrase viel in Lehrbüchern verwendet.

In der Praxis gibt es viel Überlappung, und "Beispiel für" wird oft verwendet, wenn "Beispiel zu" passender wäre. Oder es wird "Beispiel für die Verwendung" statt "Beispiel zu" verwendet.